# Is it possible to use another programming language for example python(backend) for flutter(frontend)?

Tags: python, android, ios, flutter, cross-platform

Please, Can somebody help me. I need to do cross-platform app based on flutter as frontend, and there is problem with backend. I know python very well and I want use it for my app as backend. Is it possible to use python(backend) for flutter(frontend)?

And I just started to learn flutter and don't knowing the Dart language.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can**

you can make the front end and UI of your app with flutter/dart, then you can make a backend with whatever language and technologies you want, such as node js, python, go, travel...

then you can link it and use it in your app using a REST API.

Comment: Oh , that’s what I was thinking, you help me a lot!

Comment: Good, selecting this as the right answer could help someone else to know this information

Answer (score 0):

**Frontend and backend technologies are independent**. You can use any server side language(back end) to connect with **Flutter**. server side languages(back end) are just going to provide information using **API**. I have been working Flutter with nodejs,Flutter with java. It's upto you